# insert CASE statement in user defined function SQL

Tags: postgresql

I'm new to SQL and hope to find answer on the next question:

I have written function which returns movies based on part of the title name. Now I want to add some text if the movies with the given value does not exists. For example if a movie with values '%abc%' does not exists, than return "a movie with that title was not found", otherwise return values.

Here is the function which returns values if the title exists:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION films_in_stock_by_title(x TEXT)
    RETURNS TABLE
        (film TEXT, LANGUAGE CHAR(20), customer TEXT, rental timestamptz)
AS $$
    BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY
        SELECT flm.title, lng."name", cust.first_name || ' ' || cust.last_name AS customer_name, rnt.rental_date 
        FROM customer cust
        INNER JOIN rental rnt ON rnt.customer_id = cust.customer_id 
        INNER JOIN inventory inv ON inv.inventory_id = rnt.inventory_id
        INNER JOIN film flm ON flm.film_id = inv.film_id 
        INNER JOIN LANGUAGE lng ON lng.language_id = flm.language_id 
        WHERE lower(flm.title) LIKE x
        GROUP BY flm.title, lng."name", cust.first_name || ' ' || cust.last_name, rnt.rental_date;
END; $$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

Please help me to figure out how to add CASE statement if the values do not exist.

Comment: [Don't use char](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don't_Do_This#Don.27t_use_char.28n.29)

Answer (score 0):

That should be simple. Immediately after the `RETURN QUERY` statement, add something like this:

```
IF NOT FOUND THEN
   film := 'a movie with that title was not found';
   /* assign other return values */
   RETURN NEXT;
END IF;
```

The variable `FOUND` is `TRUE` if the last SQL statement run returned or modified any rows.